# opencart - How to add the store logo to paypal's checkout page?

Tags: php, paypal, opencart

I want to display my store logo on the paypal's checkout page but I don't know how to do it. I've searched the forums but still can't find anything. Any clues?

Here's where I want it - near the header (or replaced):
http://i43.tinypic.com/2hhni54.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this link](https://cms.paypal.com/es/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)

Table 7. `image_url`